# What queue is NServiceBus using?

Tags: nservicebus, .net-4.6.1

I'm trying to work out what queue this Azure webjob is listening to.

Handler class:

```
public class InvoiceEventsHandler: IHandleMessages<InvoiceCreatedEvent>
{
    private readonly IMessagePropagator _messagePropagator;

    public InvoiceEventsHandler(IMessagePropagator messagePropagator)
    {
        _messagePropagator = messagePropagator;

    }
    public Task Handle(InvoiceCreatedEvent message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
    {
        _messagePropagator.ProcessInvoiceEvent(new GridInvoiceMessage(message.UserId));            
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Setup:

```
static class Program
{

    private static void Main()
    {
        var config = new JobHostConfiguration();

        if (config.IsDevelopment)
        {
            config.UseDevelopmentSettings();
        }

        var keyVaultFacade = new
            KeyVaultFacade(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["keyVaultSvcAccApp"],
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["keyVaultSvcAccPass"],
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["keyVaultPrefix"]);

        var configurationProvider = new ConfigurationProvider(keyVaultFacade);
        
        var host = new JobHost(config);

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder()
            .RegisterInfrastructureServiceForWebJob();

        builder
            .RegisterType<MessagePropagator>()
            .As<IMessagePropagator>()
            .SingleInstance();

        EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration = null;
        builder.RegisterBuildCallback(cont =>
        {                
            endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration(GetEndpointName(typeof(Program)));                
        });

        IEndpointInstance endpoint = null;
        builder.Register(x => endpoint)
            .As<IEndpointInstance>()
            .SingleInstance();


        var container = builder.Build();

        endpointConfiguration.UseAutofacContainer(container);

        endpoint = Endpoint.Start(endpointConfiguration).Result;

        host.RunAndBlock();
        endpoint.Stop().Wait();
    }
    
    private string GetEndpointName(Type type)
    {
        var names = type.FullName?.Split('.');
        if (names?.Length >= 4)
        {
            return string.Join(".", names[0], names[1], names[2]);
        }

        throw TypeNameException.Create(type);
    }
}
```

According to https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/endpoints/specify-endpoint-name, the queue name is specified as the argument to the `EndpointConfiguration` ctor, which will be a string containing "Program".

We don't have a queue in Azure containing the word "Program".
I'm actually expecting this service to be listening to a queue called `img-sig-queue`.
I even found this in App.config

```
<add key="notificationqueue" value="img-sig-queue" />
```

But when I search through the entire solution for `notificationqueue` or `img-sig-queue`, nothing comes up.

Comment: Try running in debug mode to identify if the method `GetEndpointName(Type)` is invoked and what's passed in.

Comment: The call to `GetEndpointName(Type)` is returning the first part of the full type name. So if you have a deep namespace, you might not make it to `Program`. i.e. If you have _CompanyName.ProjectName.ApplicationName.Program_ then your endpoint will be named `CompanyName.ProjectName.ApplicationName` and the main input queue will be based on that.